# Which are the default installed programs in Xubuntu which are safety to uninstall?

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall

Thinking that the Xubuntu could be even more slimmer/more lightware/more faster...

Tell me please are there any applications(pre-installed software) from the Standard(default) installation of Xubuntu which are not recommended to uninstall?

Even if I don't need them, it is not ok to uninstall them because they could affect the stability or the security of the system?

This question for Ubuntu(not Xubuntu) is here too, but is from 2012-2013, and I thought it would be ok to ask it again...

[Which default programs can be safely uninstalled?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139707/which-default-programs-can-be-safely-uninstalled)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xubuntu developers have been working to build a stripped-down core version called [Xubuntu Core](http://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/).  If you look at the [xubuntu-core metapackage](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xubuntu-core) you'll find what is considered currently the absolute core to keep and still be considered to be running Xubuntu.